# Cron job for windows

Tags: php, windows

In windows vps hosting server how can we set and run  the cron job for magento. Because I am using customer followup extension for that I want the cron to run for every five minutes.

Answer (score 5):

Windows usually has a task scheduler - can you not just use that?

(Start -> Accessories -> System Tools -> Scheduled Tasks/Task Scheduler) - Not sure if it exists in your server environment though